# Elm output port is not working with a signal derived from StartApp

Tags: elm, elm-signal, elm-port

We're learning Elm basics and building a simple application with some audio output with the following setup:

- We are using Elm's StartApp.
- We have ports/audio.js with some POC audio logic (and console.log).
- ATM we are using [elm-live](https://www.npmjs.com/package/elm-live) to run the application.

With a signal derived from Time.every the port works (code in ports/audio.js is run). In addition, we get "ping" logs with Debug.log.

```
port audio : Signal Int
port audio =
  Signal.map (always 400) (Time.every Time.second)
  |> Signal.map (Debug.log "ping")
```

However, when we use a signal derived from StartApp's [App](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/evancz/start-app/2.0.2/StartApp#App).model, we get a signal (since "ping" logs with Debug.log are logged) but port to JS doesn't work (code in ports/audio.js is not run)?

```
port audio : Signal Int
port audio =
  Signal.map (always 400) signalDerivedFromStartApp
  |> Signal.map (Debug.log "ping")
```

This might be some basic thing related to Elm signals/ports/StartApp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our expert friend found the issue: Our setup was broken since we used Elm.main at two places

- ports/audio.js had `Elm.worker(Elm.Main, {});`
- index.html had script with `Elm.fullscreen(Elm.Main)`

-> after removing Elm.worker things from audio.js and plugging audio.js to port implementation at index.html things were fixed.

(This is probably not a perfect/final solution for the case but fixed the issue for our current setup)